# Show div once per visit, also dissapear after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session

I want to show a div once per user session (it shows only on the fronpage for example, and then when you open subpages, it doesn't show) then hide it after 5 seconds.

Here's what I have so far. My problem is that on first load of the page, it dissapears, as it should and then every load after that, it does not.

html:

```
<a id="swipe-tooltip">Swipe Tooltip</a>
```

js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    if ( !localStorage.getItem("visited") ) {
        $("#swipe-tooltip").show().fadeIn();
        $("#swipe-tooltip").show().delay(5000).fadeOut();

        localStorage.setItem("visited", true);
    }

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) {
        localStorage.setItem("visited", false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have anything client side that can be defined as a *session*. That is a server side thing.

To keep it all client side, you could set a time in the local storage and 'end' the session after X hours. Just check in your method if the time past is more than you expect to be as a session. Additionally, you can reset the time at every page load, so you will get a sliding expiration like behavior (active users won't be 'logged out').